# Como obter um parâmetro de URL no Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Minha URL está vindo dessa forma `http://localhost:3000/menus/5.5` e está trazendo todos os registros de 5.5, porém gostaria que a URL pudesse ficar assim `http://localhost:3000/menus?price=5.5` para ter o mesmo resultado, como vocês podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que faz a consulta é essa;

```
function getMenus (req, res) {
    var price = req.params.price;
        Menus
        .find({
            price
        }).exec((err, menu)  => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: 'Error na solicitação'
                });
            }else{
                if(!menu){
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'Não existe nenhum Reviews nesse registro'
                    });
                }else{
                    res.status(200).send({
                        menu
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Ajude-me a corrigir meu código do controlador. Eu não sou capaz de obter o valor do price com a URL citada, `http://localhost:3000/menus?price=5.5`.

OBS: Por favor, o valor do atributo **price** não pode ser fixo;

OBS: Eu preciso fazer o mesmo teste com os outros atributos que são string.

No teste realizado acima foi considerado esse código;

```
router.get('/menus/:price', controller.getMenus);
```

Veja o demonstrativo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com imagem acima está sendo feito com o atributo price, mas tem que ser feito com o atributos price e description da minha entidade no Node Express.

==========================ATUALIZAÇÃO=========================

Seguindo a sugestão, meu método ficou assim;

```
function pesquisaEspecialMenus (req, res) {
        try {
            const { price, description } = req.query;
            let where = {};

            if (price) {
              where.price = price;
            }

            if (description) {
              where.description = { $regex: description, $options: 'i' };
            }

            const menu = await Menus.findOne(where).exec();

            // Caso não encontre nenhum registro para a busca especificada
            if (!menu){
              const message = 'Não existe nenhum Reviews nesse registro';
              console.error(message);
              res.status(404).send({ message });
              return;
            }

            // Se tudo correr bem
            res.status(200).send(menu);
          } catch(e) {
            const message = 'Erro na solicitação.';
            console.error(e);
            res.status(500).send({ message });
          }
    }
```

Porém o sistema está apresentando erro no **await**

Como pode ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: desculpe mas é só usar `req.query` não?

Comment: Para você usar a url que falou, teria que alterar 2 linhas de código. o seu get teria que ficar assim `router.get('/menus', controller.getMenus)` e no getMenus o price tem q vir pela query. `const price = req.query.price` .

Comment: @AMS ele funciona tranquilo com price porque price não é string, porém não acontece o mesmo com description, porque o atributo description da minha entidade  menu é um string e quando eu coloco `var description = req.query.description` e coloco `http://localhost:3000/menus?description=cidade` não funciona.

Comment: Entendi, vou realizar uns testes aqui e já retorno.

Comment: Deixa eu ver porque fiz uns testes aqui e todos funcionaram, quando você passa cidade pela query, ele nao busca no banco é isso? Você quer um filtro que identifique qual dado chegou na query e depois faça a busca com o valor relacionado? Ex: se for price, busca por ele e respectivamente com outros tipos de query, description, etc; Seria isso?

Comment: @AMS Sim para todas as suas perguntas

Comment: Você já tentou fazer dessa forma: `Menus.find(req.params)...`?

Comment: @Sorack não funcionou, ele tras todos os registros porém quando é digitado a URL `http://localhost:3000/menu?desciption=errar` ele não tras os registros correspondente, na verdade ele lista todos os registros, então não  funcionou.

Comment: Mas veja bem, está errada a descrição. `desciption` não é o nome do campo.

Comment: @Sorack desculpe, eu percebi, testei de novo, não funcionou. `http://localhost:3000/menu?description=duplo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verificando o resultado esperado vejo que você tem dois problemas. O primeiro é que você quer obter os parâmetros de acordo com a string apresentada nos parâmetros de `query`. Para tanto você precisa utilizar o atributo `query` da sua `req`:

```
const { price, description } = req.query;
```

O segundo ponto é que você quer achar um texto que **contenha** o que for passado no `description` e para tanto você pode utilizar o operador `$regex`:

```
{ description: { $regex: description, $options: 'i' } };
```

Agora juntando essas informações e permitindo que os parâmetros sejam opcionais temos o seguinte resultado no seu `controller`:

```
const getMenus = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { price, description } = req.query;
    let where = {};

    if (price) {
      where.price = price;
    }

    if (description) {
      where.description = { $regex: description, $options: 'i' };
    }

    const menu = await Menus.findOne(where).exec();

    // Caso não encontre nenhum registro para a busca especificada
    if (!menu){
      const message = 'Não existe nenhum Reviews nesse registro';
      console.error(message);
      res.status(404).send({ message });
      return;
    }

    // Se tudo correr bem
    res.status(200).send(menu);
  } catch(e) {
    const message = 'Erro na solicitação.';
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message });
  }
}
```

Você pode conferir a documentação do Mongoose para diversos tipos de condições diferentes [**aqui**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html).

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua sugestão. será que poderia verificar minha postagem, eu acabei de atualizar ela, por favor.

Comment: @wladyband como está escrito no erro, você só pode usar `await` dentro de um método `async`. Olha a diferença da declaração do método que eu fiz e o que você declarou. É só mudar isso que vai funcionar.

Comment: Nossa, cara, de fato, muito obrigado mesmo.